# Envelope Distort cards game

Tags: adobe-xd

I want to twist cards like as these cards game in below. I need them in Adobe XD so we can make it with Photoshop or Illustrator. I've tried with Adobe Illustrator 
 in this way ( Object > Envelope Distort > Make With Warp ) but it reshapes each card.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no** warp or "distortion" used to create the curve of multiple cards.

The cards are merely stacked on top of one another and then each card is rotated. This creates the "arc" overall.

[image]

Think about holding *actual* playing cards... how do you create the fan of cards.. you merely rotate them and stack them in your hand. That's all.

Comment: For me, it's not neat as yours. What did you do to rotate them like that? For mine either they are rotated in a line or manually messed up!

Comment: I rotated each card individually. After rotation you may need to slightly reposition some cards, especially those on the cuter ends.